# Error download file PDF in Yii2: Unknown Method

Tags: file, pdf, download, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to download file PDF from `frontend/web/uploads`. And I have an error in the controller (maybe):

> Calling unknown method: `frontend\controllers\BukuController::findModel()`

This is my source code:

**BukuController.php**

```
public function actionDownload($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $file ='../frontend/uploads/'.$model->file_buku;

    if(file_exists($file))
    {
        return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

And this is function in views, `views/buku/index.php`:

```
<?= Html::a('Download', ['download','id'=> $buku->file_buku]); ?>
```

(Solved)

Comment: please mark the answer as correct which helped you solve te problem

Comment: okay thankyou for reminder,

Comment: Do not add "solved" to your question title: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score 0):

As the error state, you missing in your BukuController method called `findModel`.
This method should search the model in the DB.
Something like this:

```
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (!is_null($model = Buku::findOne($id))) {
        return $model;
    }
    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
}
```

Of course if your model is not `Buku`, you need to change it relatively, and also import it in the top of the controller file:

```
use app\models\Buku; // Basic application.
use common\models\Buku; // Advanced application when models store in common folder.
use frontend\models\Buku; // Advanced application when models store in frontend folder.
```

Comment: it works! thankyou. But for download isn't worked. no action for download. how's it?

Answer (score 0):

Change `$file` variable to this.

**`$file =Yii::$app->getBasePath().'/web/uploads/'.$model->file_buku;`**